# Google App script: Function to return an arrray of unique values between 2 two ranges

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a custom function that will return an array of all of the unique values when two arrays are compared. This is what I have and it is not working:

```
function getUniqueCells(range1, range2) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range1 = sheet.getRange(range1);
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(range2);    
  var range1Val = range1.getValues();    
  var range2Val = range2.getValues();  
  var uniquesArr = [];    
  for (var i = 0; i <= range1Val.length; i++) {    
    for(var u = 0; u <= range2Val.length; i++){
      if(range1Val[i] === range2Val[u]) {
        break;
      } else if((u + 1) === range2Val.length){
        uniquesArr.push(range1Val[i]);
      };
    };
  }; 
  return uniquesArr;
}
```

Is there a way not to get the "Internal error executing the custom function" error?

Comment: First thing I would do is check returns values!  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`  `if ((sheet == null) || (sheet == undefined)) { /* say something about this error and return null or something */ }` `var range1 = sheet.getRange(range1);` `if ((range1 ...` and so on

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue on your second for loop.

for(var u = 0; u <= range2Val.length; **i++**){

it should be for(var u = 0; u <= range2Val.length; **u++**){

You cant check by `range1Val[i] === range2Val[u]`. Because they are arrays.

I had the same problem. found answer here:

[compare rows on google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960327/compare-rows-on-google-spreadsheets/)